# how to use append in for in python

Tags: python, list, append, calculator, standard-deviation

First of all, let me show my code that I wrote for calculating addition and its average.

```
def getMean (myList):
    sumVal = 0
    countVal = 0

    for n in myList:
        sumVal = sumVal + n
        countVal = countVal + 1
    return sumVal/countVal
```

This is the successful code that can calculate addition and could get its average.
And if I print it out like below:

```
ans = getMean([1, 6, 9])
print(ans)
```

> 5.333333333

the number above will come out as result.

In this situation, I want to add standard deviation using `append`.

For example, like:

```py
stdVal = []
stdVal.append(3)
```

Where can I fit those statements in my previews code?

Comment: why don't you just divide the `sumVal` by `n`

Comment: You need the mean first, so you will need a second loop following the first.  Sum the squares of the differences from the mean, then divide (by the length - 1 for unbiased sample standard deviation).  Then take the square root.

Comment: do you want the standard deviation at each step? or you want to compute against the full list ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `stdev` from `statistics` module to get your standard deviation, in your function you could return:

```
return sumVal/countVal,  statistics.stdev(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the standard deviation at each step.

```
import statistics

def getMean (myList):
    sumVal = 0
    countVal = 0
    stdVal = []

    for i in range(len(myList)):
        sumVal = sumval + myList[i]
        stdVal.append(statistics.stdev(myList[:i+1]))

        countVal = countVal + 1

    return sumVal/countVal, stdVal
```

Comment: @rusu_ro1, from question I guess he wants std dev at each position of the list. that's why he mentioned append.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def get_mean(values):
    return sum(values) / len(values)

vs = [1, 6, 9]
ans = get_mean(vs)
print(ans)

vs.append(3)
ans = get_mean(vs)
print(ans)
```

Output:

> 5.333333333333333
>
> 4.75